# SQL multiple WHERE clause problem

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I have a SQL query that puts records from one DE to another DE if that record does not exists in the second DE. The base works fine for me and i have the following query:

```
select t.Emailaddress 
from [All_subscribers_totaal] t
where t.Emailaddress not in ( 
select p.Emailaddress
from [Pak_t_Nieuws] p
)
```

But when i try to add another DE (so i want to check if a record does not exists in DE A AND B AND C etc)it does not work even i don't get an error like so:

```
select t.Emailaddress 
from [All_subscribers_totaal] t
where t.Emailaddress not in ( 
select p.Emailaddress
from [Pak_t_Nieuws] p
) 
OR t.Emailaddress not in ( 
select pm.Emailaddress
from [Pak_t_Nieuws_Medewerkers] pm
)
```

Is there something i missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly created this scenario and tested as I need to build something like this.

[image]

```
SELECT A.ID
FROM 
DE_A A
FULL OUTER JOIN  
(
SELECT ID FROM DE_B

UNION

SELECT ID FROM DE_C

) B

ON A.ID = B.ID

WHERE
A.ID is null OR  B.ID IS NULL
```

Your SQL should be as follow..

```
select t1.Emailaddress 
from [All_subscribers_totaal] t1
full outer join
(
select Emailaddress
from 
[Pak_t_Nieuws] 

UNION

select Emailaddress
from
Pak_t_Nieuws_Medewerkers

) t2
ON t1.Emailaddress = t2.Emailaddress

WHERE
t2.Emailaddress IS NULL
```

Comment: You can join UNION as many Data extension you want and exclude from source

Comment: This will return results from any of the DEs. OP just wanted those in original table that did not exist inside of the other DEs.

Comment: Thanks  Gortonington,
To achieve that he just change the where clause to 
where t2.Emailaddress IS NULL

Comment: correct - I wanted to comment so you can adjust your answer to fit the posters request.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But i got the same issue. I got this error problem: Query failed during execution. Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Contact_delete'. The duplicate key value is (Emailaddres form a record).

If i make the Emailaddress not primary i got an error that at least i should have 1 primary key and 1 non primary. How can i solve this problem? I can try another field as 2 primary keys but i don't get the query right for it

Comment: I did a new test and it seems to work now. I just added the Subscriberkey to it so like this:

    select t1.Emailaddress, SubscriberKey 
    from [All_subscribers_totaal] t1
    full outer join

In the DE i have now Emailaddres and SubscirberKey as primary key and this was a succesfull run. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in this case instead of making multiple WHERE statements is to UNION inside of a single NOT EXISTS statement.

```
select t.Emailaddress 
from [All_subscribers_totaal] t
where NOT EXISTS ( 
  select p.Emailaddress
  from [Pak_t_Nieuws]

  UNION

  select pm.Emailaddress
  from [Pak_t_Nieuws_Medewerkers] pm
)
```

Using NOT IN, should have the same effect, but I usually lean towards NOT EXISTS or LEFT JOIN with `WHERE 2ndtable.pkey IS NULL`

If this still returns empty results, I would verify that

1. It is not timing out or otherwise erroring
2. That there are values inside that DE that do not exist in the other DEs

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still no results and i see no errors. But what do you mean with values inside the DE that do nog exist in the other DE's? I only ask for the Emailaddress right?

Comment: yes, make sure that there are values that should be pulled into your target DE

Answer (score 0):

Try the left join approach

This should return any emails that exist in [All_subscribers_totaal] and not in the either of the other 2 DE. Change the OR to a AND if you would like to retrieve records if they don't exist in both DE's

`SELECT t.Emailaddress
from [All_subscribers_totaal] t
left join [Pak_t_Nieuws] p ON p.Emailaddress = t.Emailaddress
left join [Pak_t_Nieuws_Medewerkers] pm ON pm.Emailaddress = t.Emailaddress
Where p.Emailaddress is null OR pm.Emailaddress is null`

Comment: Hi Noor Alam, Thanks for your answer. I tried your option and got this error problem:

Query failed during execution. Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Contact_delete'. The duplicate key value is (Emailaddres form a record). If i make the Emailaddress not primary i got an error that at least i should have 1 primary key and 1 non primary. How can i solve this problem? I can try another field as 2 primary keys but i don't get the query right for it.

Comment: Sounds like you have duplicate email address being inserted in to the DE. Try `SELECT DISTINCT T.Emailaddress` in the SQL and have the PK as Email Address